# AJAX/Jquery - Get response from php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

Hi I have a php file that when called by my ajax/jquery code inserts a row into a mySQL table. However I want some sort of feedback to know whether the insertion was successfull or not. Here is my current code:

ajax/jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    success: function(){
        alert("success");    
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$conn = "";
try {
    $conn = new PDO( "mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo "Cannot connect to database, try again later";
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data (price) VALUES (:price)");
$stmt->bindParam(":price", $price);
$stmt->execute();
$conn=null;
```

Comment: `$echo` should be `echo`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Fixed. Also price is a variable declared earlier on

Comment: If there is an error setting `$conn`, I imagine `$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data (price) VALUES (:price)");` is going to fail...  Might want this whole code in your try block.

Comment: @guydog28 but how will that alert me via the ajax code whether it was successful or not?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins it does not.  The answers below show you how to return the result.  I'm just helping you see see that you have other dangers lurking.  You'll need to return results like the answers below at the end of your `try` block, and additionally at the end of your `catch` block return an error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a feedback and send it to the `jQuery.ajax` you may use

```
if($stmt->execute()) { // returns true on success
    exit('success'); // Prints success and exit the script
}
else{ // returns false on fail
    exit('error'); // Prints error and exit the script
}
```

In the client side, in your `success` callback

```
success: function(data){
    alert(data); // either error or success
}
```

Or you may check it like

```
if(data == 'success') {
    // ok
}
```

Also, where is your `$price` variable, i didn't see it and as i mrntioned in comment that `$echo` should be `echo`.

Comment: I feel it is important to mention that `error` has nothing to do with an 'unsuccessful' response but a failed request. Any response received leads to the `success` handler, `error` is only called for statuses other than 400. Moreover, they don't even take the same parameters.

Comment: @Derija93, I  didn't add any error method here, which one you are talking about ?

Comment: I dont get any alert message regardless of success or failure

Comment: @Matt9Atkins, Then check your `success` and make sure it's `function(data){ //... }` and also your browser's console to find out the error.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I have used the functions for success that your provided. It doesnt alert me.

Comment: @Matt9Atkins, check your browser's console and find out the error .

Comment: @SheikhHeera Sorry, I was referring to the author's incorrect use of `error`.

Comment: @Derija93, Oh! it's ok and don't be sorry :-)

Answer (score 8):

principal example, you can do much more to connect feedback vs javascript handling

```
$.ajax({
  url: "update.php",
  data: $('#form_id').serialize(),
  dataType: "json",
  timeout: 15000,    
  success: function(response){
    switch(response.status){
      case 'saved':
        alert(response.message); // do what you want
      break;
      case 'empty':
        alert(response.message);
      break;
      default:
        alert("unknown response");
    }  
   },
   error:function(){
    alert("failure");
   }
});


// remote php file
<?php

    // on database success or whatever
      $return_arr["status"] = 'saved';
      $return_arr["message"] = utf8_encode("Your data ".$name." was saved");
      echo json_encode($return_arr);
      exit();

?>
```

Comment: best solution in my humble opinion

Answer (score 1):

In PHP section you can do this:

```
$conn = "";
try {
    $conn = new PDO( "mysql:host=XXX;dbname=XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo "Cannot connect to database, try again later";
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO data (price) VALUES (:price)");
$stmt->bindParam(":price", $price);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();// Returns the number of rows affected by the last SQL statement
$conn=null;
if ($count > 0)
{
    $res = "success";
}
else
{
    $res = "error";
}
//maybe you need to encode the result to use in your js ajax functions!
json_encode($res);
exit();
```